# Thumbnails keep disappearing from Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-10, windows-media-player, thumbnails

Got a strange issue with Windows Media Player on one of my PCs. When you first load it up, the thumbnails load fine but as soon as you start navigating around all album art and video thumbnails vanish.

I've tried:

- Reverting back to the 2004 version of Windows 10 (at least twice)
- Un-installing and then re-installing Windows Media Player (at least twice)
- Clearing the thumbnail cache (multiple times)

There's no problems with thumbnails in Windows Explorer, thumbnails generate there ok (I use WinThumbsPreloader to generate them).

I've got the latest version of the K-Lite Codec Pack installed.

Is there anything else that I could try, before I try resorting to a complete re-install of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Done a Windows Reset on the PC, didn't help.

I upgraded to the latest K-Lite codec pack on my other PC and suddenly got the same problem, so used System Restore to go back to the old version on that PC, so will have to download and install an older version on the original PC.

I'm guessing that it must be a conflict between codecs, as to if it's on the K-Lite side or the Windows side, I've no idea